# Permanently change Node call stack size

Tags: node.js

I want to increase the `--stack-size` option for nodejs system-wide.

I know I can do this on a per invocation basis like this:

```
node --stack-size=10000 <app>
```

But I want to set the stack size system wide to this value for all users and for cron tasks.

I'm on Ubuntu 13.

Answer (score 2):

You can:

1. Rename /usr/bin/node (or whatever you actual path to node is) to /usr/bin/node_bin
2. Create shell script in place of old node executable (at /usr/bin/node) with following content:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   /usr/bin/node_bin --stack-size=10000 $@
   ```

This way you don't have to change absolute references to node in all the cron scripts.

Answer (score 0):

For windows, using the same approach as https://stackoverflow.com/users/8109341/daniel 's answer:

1. Rename `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe` to `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_origin.exe`
2. Create `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.cmd` with the following contents:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET "NODE_EXE=C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_origin.exe"
echo Running node with '--stack-size=4096'

"%NODE_EXE%" "--stack-size=4096" %*
```

Answer (score 0):

## Context

To iterate on https://stackoverflow.com/users/8109341/daniel 's answer:

On Ubuntu, I had to wrap `$@` in double quotes: `"$@"`, otherwise passing arguments would break:

E.g.:

Running `npx ganache-cli -m "strike artwork yard vault enhance despair online sock feed cactus subject rebela" -i 15`

Would have `process.argv` evaluated to:

```
[ '/usr/bin/node_bin',
  '/home/daniel/repos/aragon/aragen/node_modules/.bin/ganache-cli',
  '-m',
  'strike',
  'artwork',
  'yard',
  'vault',
  'enhance',
  'despair',
  'online',
  'sock',
  'feed',
  'cactus',
  'subject',
  'rebel',
  '-i',
  '15']
```

instead of:

```
[ '/usr/bin/node_bin',
  '/home/daniel/repos/aragon/aragen/node_modules/.bin/ganache-cli',
  '-m',
  'strike artwork yard vault enhance despair online sock feed cactus subject rebel',
  '-i',
  '15']
```

## TL;DR

1. Rename the node binary:
   `sudo mv /usr/bin/node /usr/bin/node_bin`
2. Create the shell script:

```sh
cat << EOF | sudo tee /usr/bin/node
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/node_bin --stack-size=4096 "\$@"
EOF
```

3. Make the shell script executable:
   `sudo chmod +x node`