# How to change stack size of node for npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, stack

I want to increase nodes stack size while running npm install. I've tried using `NODE_OPTIONS` but it disallows the `--stack-size` option. The best solution I've seen so far is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44398946/4208955 but it seems there should be an easier way to pass node flags to npm.

Comment: What version of `nodejs` are you using?

Comment: 9.11.2 or 10.7.0, depending on the project.

Comment: I think this https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12238#issuecomment-367147962 can help you

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it seems that `stack-size` and `max-stack-size` are disallowed from NODE_OPTIONS. Can't find  clear documentation but node throws this error: `node: --stack-size=4096 is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS`